# Функция, которая ожидает ввод на протяжении определенного времени

Tags: c++, linux, curses

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу аналог тэтриса на консоле и задался таким вопросом: как создать функцию на `с++` (использую также `ncurses`, пишу на `linux`), которая запрашивает ввод, но если в течении определенного времени (например 1 секунда) ввода не произошло - выполняет дефолтное действие, а если ввод был, то действие в соответствии с вводом. Что-то типа:

```
if (ввода_нет) {
    do_something();
}
else {
    switch (input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Знаю что что-то подобное работает в `curses` при включении `keypad()`, но не хватат знаний, чтобы написать что-то подобное. Хотя бы толкните в верном направлении. СПС!

Comment: Ничего стандартного в рамках языков C/C++ AFAIK пока нет, на *nix-системах для низкоуровневого ввода из файловых дескрипторов используются либо вызовы poll() или select (), либо неблокирующий ввод-вывод (установка на fd == 1 `fcntl ()`), оба механизма используются в основном для сетевого программирования, поэтому изучать их лучше в контексте оного, а для стандартного ввода/вывода сделать отдельный поток обычно проще...

Comment: poll/select это абсолютно нормально для подобной программы

Comment: Можно поподробнее что за pull/select?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, [`poll()`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=poll&category=2&russian=0), а не pull )), в [`man 2 select`](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=select&category=2&russian=0#lbAH) есть пример ожидания stdin'а с задержкой времени, но в качестве платы придётся отказаться от использования буферизированных потоков c/c++ и работать напрямую `read()`'ом. (можно конечно продолжать и через потоки, но это грязно и сильно чревато ошибками).

Comment: кстати, а в чём именно суть вопроса «как сделать это средствами curses» или «как сделать нечто подобное тому что делает curses»?

Comment: Как сделать нечто подобное тому, что делает curses - вот суть вопроса. Впринципе, я уже нашел решение благодаря select. Еще не понял как это работает (так как еще не знаком с потоками), но решение рабочее и для моей задачи подходит.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, потоки (streams) — это стандартные примитивы ввода/вывода c/c++ (т.е. stdin/stdout/std::cin/std::cout итд).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На случай, если кому-то будет полезно:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/select.h>
#include<curses.h>

int main(void) {
initscr();
refresh();

fd_set rfds;
struct timeval tv;
int retval;
int a{0};
FD_ZERO(&rfds);
FD_SET(0, &rfds);
tv.tv_sec = 5;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
retval = select(1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
if (retval) {
    scanw("%i", &a);
    printw("Data in.\n");
}
else {
    printw("No data.\n");
    a = 0;
}
printw("\n%i\n", a);
getch();

endwin();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - создать отдельный поток в котором периодически (например 1 раз в 10 миллисекунд) опрашивать ввод. Если ввод есть, то делать что положено. Если ввода нет в течении 100 опросов (то есть в течении искомой секунды), то делать что положено по дефолту.

> А как "опрашивать ввод"?

Давно я в консоли не работал. Но что-то вроде того:

```
    for(;;){


    int i;

    for(i=0;i!=100;++i){

    char ch=0;

    cin>>ch;

    if(ch!=0) break;

    //здесь задержка на 1-10 мс

    }

    //здесь набираете строку из символов и анализируете команду

    }
```

Учтите, что

```
cin>>ch;
```

может блокировать ввод и ждать до посинения, что будет введен символ. Погуглите, в интернете должно быть написано как сделать неблокирующий ввод. Я когда-то делал, но давно это было, сейчас не помню.

Если же можно обойтись непереносимым решением, то скорее всего в линуксе есть системный запрос к консоли, в котором можно указать таймаут ожидания ввода. Тут нужно курить маны.

> а один поток занимается только обработкой ввода и висит в ожидании на
>   нём, а второй делает что-то полезное практически независимо от него...

Обычно так и делают. Но тут человек пишет, что ему надо, чтобы если ввода нет в течении секунды, то начиналось какое-то действие.

Немного подумал и придумал такой алгоритм:

1. Создаются ТРИ потока.
2. Первый поток висит на блокирующем вводе и ждет ввода. Если ввод есть, то введенные данные передаются второму потоку. Если ввода нет, поток ничего не делает и ждет ввода.
3. Второй поток ждет данные от первого потока и считает таймаут. Если данных нет больше секунды, то второй поток формирует псевдо-данные и передает их третьему потоку. Если данные есть, то поток передает их третьему потоку напрямую.
4. Третий поток получает данные ввода и выполняет работу в зависимости от команды.

Все общение между потоками естественно должно быть защищено семафорами или другими объектами синхронизации.

Comment: А как "опрашивать ввод"?

Comment: Обычно при использовании потоков не «опрашивают ввод», а один поток занимается только обработкой ввода и висит в ожидании на нём, а второй делает что-то полезное практически независимо от него...

Comment: лол, третий поток уж точно лишний... в любом случае передача данных между потоками происходит требует какой-то синхронизации (или особой магии неблокирующих структур), обычно — это мьютекс, а для ожидания блокировки детерминированное количество времени есть [`std::timed_mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex).