# Помогите реализовать управление в тетрисе

Tags: c++, windows

Вообщем есть готовый тетрис без управления.Подкиньте идей как его реализовать.Знаю функцию getch() что бы снимать нажатие клавиш.Но мне нужно как-то на секунду задержку сделать во время которой я могу управлять фигуркой клавишами.И после этого она уже падает.То есть секунда прошла - фигурка упала.И во время этой секунды я могу ее перемещать, переворачивать и.т.д.

P.S. Слыхал что там какие-то потоки есть когда можно пару кусков кода одновременно выполнять.Но я еще до них не добрался, поэтому как-то без них пожалуйста

Comment: Какая операционка и как собираетесь делать вывод? Но в любом случае потоки сдесь не нужны (хотя можно сделать и с ними)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Widnows и обычная консоль

Comment: в обычной консоли без библиотеки текстового ввода вывода это будет выглядеть странно

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция, которая ожидает ввод на протяжении определенного времени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/814899/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Comment: в любом случае смотрите в сторону опроса ввода. Если не пользуетесь библиотекой текстого интерфейса (аля `curses`), то это можно сделать через api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой вариант пойдет?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

enum special_keys
{
// можно выбрать любое значение которое > 255 (для char)
    left = 300,
    up,
    right,
    down
};

enum
{
    _ascii_left = 75,
    _ascii_up = 72,
    _ascii_right = 77,
    _ascii_down = 80 
};

// возвращает ascii-символ нажатой клавиши
// или номер спец.символа, если была нажата спец.клавиша
int get_key()
{
    int key = _getch();
    if (_kbhit())
    {
        key = _getch();
        switch (key)
        {
        case _ascii_left:
            return left;
        case _ascii_up:
            return up;
        case _ascii_down:
            return down;
        case _ascii_right:
            return right;
        default:
            return key;
        }
    }
    return key;
}

// возвращает ноль если клавиша в данный момент не нажата
// в противном случае возвращает нажатый символ (ascii)
int get_async_key()
{
// Изменение!
// на месте _getch теперь get_key
    if (_kbhit())
        return get_key();
    return 0;
}

// возвращает ноль если клавиша в заданное время не была нажата
// в противном случае возвращает нажатый символ (ascii)
int get_async_key(long long moments)
{
    // todo: проверка moments должен быть > 0
    int pressed_key = 0;
    for (; moments; --moments)
    {
        pressed_key = get_async_key();
        if (pressed_key)
            return pressed_key;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // test
    int key = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        key = get_async_key(50000);
        if (!key)
            std::cout << "Timeout\n";
        else if (key == special_keys::left)
            std::cout << "You've pressed left arrow key\n";
        // ...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Дело в том, что при нажатии управляющей клавиши (например стрелочки или f1-f12) функция `_getch()` возвращает специальное значение и в очереди нажатых клавиш остается номер нажатой клавиши. Но существует еще один подводный камень: эти значения принадлежат не только стрелочкам, но и другим 'обычным' символам(буквам). Т.е. для того, чтобы определить была ли нажата стрелочка, мы должны

1. Получить значение с клавиатуры при помощи `_getch()`
2. Проверить есть ли в очереди еще нажатые клавиши.

   3a. Если нажатые клавиши есть значить идентифицировать нажатую клавишу и преобразовать ответ в **уникальное** значение.

   3б. Если нажатых клавиш больше нет, то пользователь ввел обычный символ и никаких действий, кроме возвращения значения больше не требуется.

Вспомогательная функция `get_key` расчитана на клавиши стрелок, таким же образом можно сделать обработку нажатий клавиш f1-f12 и остальных спец.клавиш.

Comment: В теории должен на практике не работает

Comment: @Hujuk, что не так? не со стрелочками случайно проблемы?

Comment: как раз именно с ними

Comment: @Hujuk, обновил ответ.

Comment: Уже сам нагуглил, но все равно спасибо